# What is the command called in Cinema4D that brings up the four camera views?

Tags: cinema4d, camera

It was originally mapped to MMB, but I changed the shortcut and now I want to bind it to something else, but I don't know what the command is called. It is the property which brings up four viewport panels altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"4 Views", as seen in Customize Commands... no further information is revealed.